# Need help while generating reference no using php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

My code is:

`$regno = 'B'.date('Ymd');`

for generating reference no. for registered user.
if 2 user is registered on July 15, 2016. and 3 user is registered on next day then
I want to generate ref, No.

### for 1st day

B201607151 for 1st user

B201607152 for 2nd user

---

### 2nd day

B201607161 for 1st user

B201607162 for 2nd user

B201607163 for 3rd user

---

So what kind of changes i should make in my code.
Please advise.

Comment: can you rewrite the question, its a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you get the last reference, you put it for example in `$last_ref`, Then you get the last sequential of the current day, then you increment that sequential, try this :

```
$regno = 'B'.date('Ymd');
if($last_ref) // check if there is a reference in the current day
{
    $sequential = str_replace($regno,'',$last_ref);
    $new_reference = $regno.($sequential+1);
}
else $new_reference = $regno.'1';
```

I hope that will help you.